# Redirecting webpage to a file

Tags: javascript, html, apache, redirect

Suppose a webpage that presents a table, but with an option to download it as an Excel sheet. The option is presented as a button that submits a form (containing the required parameters to create the same report, but for Excel).

```
<form action="makereport.blah">
<!-- Some parameters -->
<input type="button" value="Export to Excel" onClick="submit();"/>
</form>
```

The final step remains to direct the browser to the created Excel sheet.

I see three possibilities:

1. In the "action" page of the form, with the OnLoad event: rewrite in JavaScript the URL to the created file path and reload the page
2. In the HTTP header: Redirect to the url of the file (with the Redirect command)
3. Using an `iframe`, where `src` is the target file

Those seem a bit *hackish*, but I've used them in the past. **How is this normally done?**

(As a note, the language I'm using to generate the HTML (and Excel sheet) is an in-house solution. So if PHP has something for that, I would just have to port it).

Comment: Chances are you're going to have to re-generate the data on the server, but catere the output for excel. Maybe take a look at [excel-generating libraries for PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/psxlsgen/)? (I use PHP as this was a language you mentioned, though there are surely other languages available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script/code that handles the posting of the form (server side) can generate the Excel spreadsheet. Then instead of replying with an HTML response (or some kind of redirect) you can instead return the spreadsheet directly (with the correct HTTP headers that would be sent if the file was loaded directly).

An example in PHP:

```
<?php

// generate spreadsheet in file
$file = do_something_to_generate_spreadsheet();

// specifies it is an excel spreadsheet response
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"'); // filename
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); // length

readfile($file); // sends file to client

?>
```

Comment: This is nice. And `$file` is what, just the filename or the path to it?

Comment: Never mind, found it, filename just that, the file name. Sounds silly put like this, but it's not always the case!

Answer (score 3):

Possibility 4 (the right one): the PHP script this form points to should send a `Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel` [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) then the contents of the Excel file. If it's an actual file on disk, use `readfile`, otherwise just `echo` the Excel data straight out. If you want to specify a filename for download, you can also send a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='filename'` header.

Answer (score 0):

Why have a second page at all?  Make `makereport.blah` the `xls` file itself instead of another HTML document.

Comment: Because makereport.xls will only be created on demand. I can't direct the user to it until it is created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATAURI scheme in new file to insert file in base64 mode. i'll make a script tonight.

Comment: I'm still interested in seeing what that would look like, if it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Using base64 code from webtoolkit.info and disassembling an XML/XLS file i have tried make a script to force to download a file made in the air. I make a windows object and when this will open, then insert XML/XLS code codified with base64. this method is a hack of dataURI. I have not put a name when the file download. 
I tried on google chrome.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9M5cW/) an jsfiddle of file.

Thanks for your interest.