# In J, 1!:2&4 replaces LF with CRLF. Is there a way to keep it as LF?

Tags: j

I have a modified boot.ijs script for J which allows J to respond to a request from Apache.

Essentially, in httpd.conf, I have this:

```
ScriptAlias /j/ "C:/J/"
DirectoryIndex index.ijs
AddType application/x-httpd-ijs .ijs
Action application/x-httpd-ijs "/j/j.exe"
```

Which tells Apache to send all *.ijs urls to J. That's just here for the context.

J can then answer by writing to the **standard output** with:

```
echo =: 1!:2&4
```

I have binary data (an Excel file) that I create, then want to send back to the asker's browser, such as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878620/redirecting-webpage-to-a-file). However, in the file itself, all LF's are changed to CRLF.

This behaviour can be "observed" in jconsole.exe. Type in the declaration for echo above, and send the commands:

```
echo LF
echo CR
echo LF
```

You will see that there's one more line after each `echo LF`, because in the console CR is just written as a single line. In essence, J translates LF to CRLF.

The question: How do you turn it off, make J respect what is actually asked to be outputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned from their forum that J always outputs as text, never as binary, which means LF is always going to be replaced with CRLF. Huge disappointment.